# Perfect Scrollbar simple gap customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, perfect-scrollbar

Hi this regarding jquery plugin perfect-scrollbar.

I want a gap between two scrollbar.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

CSS:
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  background: url('https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/azusa.jpg') top left no-repeat;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 720px;
}
JS:


   $('.container').perfectScrollbar();
```

See the demo here

https://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/gbfLazpx/

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Update the classes for `ps-scrollbar-x-rail` and `ps-scrollbar-y-rail` to add some `margin-right` and `margin-bottom` respectively. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbfLazpx/595/)

Increase/decrease the values to your liking.

Comment: Thanks a lot jack. It Worked.